# How to make particles appear when an object is moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2D game in Unity. I want to have an object have particles when they move or when being pushed. I am still a beginner at this, all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Particle System. Under "Emission", enter the desired value at "Rate over Distance". This will create particles, whenever the object moves. No particles emitted when the object remains still. Per default, there is a value in "Rate over time" which will emit continuously.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysEmissionModule.html